# boto3 create auto scaling group

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-auto-scaling

I'm trying to create an auto-scaling group with different templates and types using boto3,

hopefully, someone can assist me here :)
This is the code I used:

```
import boto3


client = boto3.client('autoscaling')


def create_auto_scaling_group(**kwargs):
    response = client.create_auto_scaling_group(
        AutoScalingGroupName='TEST-ASG',
        LaunchTemplate={
            'LaunchTemplateName': 'TEST-Template',
            'Version': '5'
        },
        MixedInstancesPolicy={
            'LaunchTemplate': {
                'LaunchTemplateSpecification': {
                    'LaunchTemplateName': 'TEST-Template',
                    'Version': '5'
                },
                'Overrides': [
                    {
                        'InstanceType': 'g4dn.xlarge',
                        'LaunchTemplateSpecification': {
                            'LaunchTemplateName': 'TEST-Template',
                            'Version': '5'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        'InstanceType': 'g3s.xlarge',
                        'LaunchTemplateSpecification': {
                            'LaunchTemplateName': 'TEST-Template',
                            'Version': '4'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        'InstanceType': 'p3.2xlarge',
                        'LaunchTemplateSpecification': {
                            'LaunchTemplateName': 'TEST-Template',
                            'Version': '6'
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
            'InstancesDistribution': {
                'OnDemandBaseCapacity': 0,
                'OnDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity': 0,
                'SpotAllocationStrategy': 'capacity-optimized',
            }
        },
        MinSize=0,
        MaxSize=0,
        DesiredCapacity=0,
        AvailabilityZones=[
            'string',
            'string',
            'string',
        ],
        Tags=[
            {
                'ResourceId': 'TEST-ASG',
                'ResourceType': 'auto-scaling-group',
                'Key': 'Name',
                'Value': 'TEST-ASG',
                'PropagateAtLaunch': True
            },
        ],
    )

create_auto_scaling_group()
```

I am getting the following response and cant seem to find whats causing it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/bena/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/New/AutoScaleOverride.py", line 69, in <module>
    create_auto_scaling_group()
  File "c:/Users/bena/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/New/AutoScaleOverride.py", line 8, in create_auto_scaling_group
    response = client.create_auto_scaling_group(
  File "C:\Users\bena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 357, in _api_call       
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateAutoScalingGroup operation: Valid requests must contain either LaunchTemplate, LaunchConfigurationName, InstanceId or MixedInstancesPolicy parameter.
```

On a separate aws-cli script I tried, it worked, meaning everything was created without errors.

First time trying this, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have defined a function called `create_auto_scaling_group`, but I can't see where the function is being called.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yeah sorry, edited the post with the new response I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to manage by myself :)

Adding here what worked for me:

```
import boto3


client = boto3.client('autoscaling')


response = client.create_auto_scaling_group(
    AutoScalingGroupName='ASGName',
    MixedInstancesPolicy={
        'LaunchTemplate': {
            'LaunchTemplateSpecification': {
                'LaunchTemplateId': 'Id',
                'Version': '5'
            },
            'Overrides': [
                {
                    'InstanceType': 'g4dn.xlarge',
                    'LaunchTemplateSpecification': {
                        'LaunchTemplateId': 'Id',
                        'Version': '5'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'InstanceType': 'g3s.xlarge',
                    'LaunchTemplateSpecification': {
                        'LaunchTemplateId': 'Id',
                        'Version': '4'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'InstanceType': 'p3.2xlarge',
                    'LaunchTemplateSpecification': {
                        'LaunchTemplateId': 'Id',
                        'Version': '6'
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        'InstancesDistribution': {
            'OnDemandBaseCapacity': 0,
            'OnDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity': 0,
            'SpotAllocationStrategy': 'capacity-optimized',
        }
    },
    MinSize=0,
    MaxSize=0,
    DesiredCapacity=0,
    VPCZoneIdentifier='subnet-1, subnet-2, subnet-3',
    Tags=[
        {
            'ResourceId': 'ASGName',
            'ResourceType': 'auto-scaling-group',
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': 'ASGName',
            'PropagateAtLaunch': True
        },
    ],
)

print(response)
```